# consolibyte | example_mysql_mirror | syncing related questions

Tags: php, mysql, quickbooks

I am using  consolibyte "mysql_mirror script" for two way syncing. Till now syncing is working perfectly but there are questions related to syncing.

1. We want customer billing and shipping address without First Name and Last Name. Requirement is to get only customer's address that is valid and can be used in google maps API. Question is that 
   Is it possible through code modification or any other way to get customer's clear address.
2. Customer's Mobile and Website information is not synced from QBD to MySQL. Is it possible through code modification to sync this information and if yes, can you please give me direction what code modification is required to sync it.
3. Some tables are not synced from QBD to MySQL like "qb_unitofmeasureset". Is there any page that specifies the list of tables that wouldn't be synced?
4. As per my understanding if i set mode to MODE_READWRITE and use only QUICKBOOKS_OBJECT_** option for customer type, then two way sync will work correctly. 
   What is the purpose of other three 
   QUICKBOOKS_ADD_CUSTOMERTYPE', 
   QUICKBOOKS_QUERY_CUSTOMERTYPE'
   QUICKBOOKS_IMPORT_CUSTOMERTYPE

I see these four actions for other entities as well.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you read this first:

- http://consolibyte.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=20

And:

- https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php/blob/master/docs/web_connector/example_mysql_mirror.php

> We want customer billing and shipping address without First Name and Last Name.

The data synced is the data in QuickBooks. If QuickBooks has the first/last name in it, then the data that gets synced will have the first/last name in it.

> Customer's Mobile and Website information is not synced from QBD to MySQL. Is it possible through code modification to sync this information

You should refer to the QuickBooks OSR for this. If it's accessible in the OSR, you should be able to add support for it.

I *think* you'd have to add the fields in here: 
https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php/tree/master/QuickBooks/QBXML/Schema/Object

But I'm not 100% sure.

> Some tables are not synced from QBD to MySQL like "qb_unitofmeasureset". Is there any page that specifies the list of tables that wouldn't be synced?

I don't have this information anywhere, no.

> What is the purpose of other three QUICKBOOKS_ADD_CUSTOMERTYPE', QUICKBOOKS_QUERY_CUSTOMERTYPE' QUICKBOOKS_IMPORT_CUSTOMERTYPE

These are used in other parts of the framework. They are NOT used with the SQL mirror code.

Comment: Thank you keith! I really appreciate your cooperation.